# correct use of getContextPath() on jsp

Tags: image, jsp, reference

I have a problem using getContextPath() on jsp.

I want to add an image to the JSP, a logo.

I have read that is better to use getContextPath().

In my browser´s address bar I see de URL:

**http://local.host:9080/Cold/start/Result.jsp**

So I have assumed my getContextPath() is:

**http://local.host:9080/Cold/**

Next, I found the Result.jsp file at:

**C:\Users\myname\IBM\rationalsdp\workspace\Cold_WEB\WebContent\start**

So I have created the next path:

**C:\Users\myname\IBM\rationalsdp\workspace\Cold_WEB\WebContent\images**

And I have put the logo file there.

So, I have added next code:

```
<img src='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/SuperlineaPF.gif' border="0">
```

But, I still can not see the logo at the page on the browser.

What is wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I find the following graphic from [HttpServletRequest Path Decoding](https://agiletribe.purplehillsbooks.com/2016/02/23/httpservletrequest-path-decoding/)  helpful:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the EL expression ${pageContext.request.contextPath}

Answer (score -1):

You can do it following way in your `JSP`

```
<c:set var="context" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/SuperlineaPF.gif"/>
<img alt="image" src="${context }" border="0"/>
```

At the top of the page put an uri for `JSTL` as

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

`Note:` You'll require `JSTL` library for it. This is for best practice.

Since your `JSPs` are placed under `start` in `WebContent` you can simply refer to your images following way.

```
<img alt="image" src="images/SuperlineaPF.gif"/>
```

You do not `require page` context for that.